# Pandas Renaming columns based on cipher

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a column in a dataframe with sensor identifiers and varying values. I have another dataframe which contains a plain English description of the sensor names. It looks something like this:

```
Date          zz8029    df456sz
2017-01-01    1            2
...           .            .
...           .            .
```

The cipher, second dataframe looks like this:

```
name     description
zz8029   ROOM201-TEMP
```

Is there a way to programatically rename all of my colums in the first dataframe, using the cipher second dataframe? There are hundreds of sensors names so manually renaming them wont do it. The result would look something like this

```
Date          ROOM201-TEMP    ROOM200-TEMP
2017-01-01    1                2
...           .                .
...           .                .
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) where the arg is a series with index of "from value" and values are what is mapped to:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.columns = df.columns.map(df2.set_index('name')['description'])
df = df.reset_index()
df
```

Output:

```
         Date  ROOM201-TEMP  ROOM200-TEMP
0  2017-01-01             1             2
```

Answer (score 1):

there is, good old `pd.map`. It's meant for series but I think it is possible to make it work for column names

```
 z = {k: g.description.values[0] for k, g in df2.groupby('name')}
 df.columns = df.columns.map(z)
```

Comment: Scott posted while I was writing, but you can see that we agree on the use of map